# Complement of the Cantor set intersect an open ball?

Tags: general-topology, cantor-set

I know that the complement of the Cantor set can be written as the countable union of disjoint intervals i.e. $[0,1]\backslash K=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n$. However I was told that if $x\not\in \bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\overline{I_n}$, then there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if $I_n\cap(x-\delta, x +\delta)\neq \varnothing$ then $\overline{I_n}\subseteq(x-\delta,x+\delta)$. I'm not sure why this is true, and am starting to doubt whether it is in fact true.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $x\in[0,1]$, just take $\delta=2$: then $\operatorname{cl}I_n\subseteq(x-\delta,x+\delta)$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. If $x<0$, take $\delta=-x$, and if $x>1$, take $\delta=x-1$; then $I_n\cap(x-\delta,x+\delta)=\varnothing$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$. Thus, the statement is true for all $x\in\Bbb R$, but for trivial reasons. Are you sure that you have the right statement of the result?